# Call stored function in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm getting some difficulties to call a stored function within mongdb.
I'm a little bit newbie with mongo.

[EDIT] : my function stored in mongodb

```
function() {
    var cndTime = new Date().getTime() - (3600*1000*24*2); // condition
     db.urls.find(needParse: false).forEach(function(item){
        if(item.date < cndTime)  // check
            db.urls.update({_id: item._id}, {$set: { needParse: true }}); // update field
     });
}
```

All I'm asking is how to invoke this function using reactivemongo or native API.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Strange how everyone answers in console yet the question was and is tagged with java `:\`

Comment: Don't use javascript functions for this kind of features on the server as they can 1.only run on the primary and 2.need to take a write lock on the db during the whole execution causing a drop in throughput.

Answer (score 17):

Consider the following example from the mongo shell that first saves a function named `echoFunction` to the `system.js` collection and calls the function using `db.eval()`:

```js
db.system.js.save({
    _id: "echoFunction",
    value: function (x) {
        return 'echo: ' + x;
    }
})

db.eval("echoFunction('test')") // -> "echo: test"
```

`echoFunction(...)` is available in `eval`/`$where`/`mapReduce` etc. more information is available at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server

Comment: I don't think it was useful to op though since this won't work in Java

Comment: This won't even work in JavaScript, only in the shell

Comment: db.eval is deprecated written on output

Answer (score 16):

In the mongo shell, you can use db.loadServerScripts() to load all the scripts saved in the system.js collection for the current database. Once loaded, you can invoke the functions directly in the shell, as in the following example

```
db.loadServerScripts();

mySampleFunction(3, 5);
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a special system collection named

> system.js

that can store JavaScript functions for reuse.

To store a function, you can use the

> db.collection.save()

, as in the following examples:

```
db.system.js.save(
 {
     _id: "echoFunction",
     value : function(x) { return x; }
 }
);

db.system.js.save(
 {
    _id : "myAddFunction" ,
    value : function (x, y){ return x + y; }
 }
);
```

The **_id** field holds the name of the function and is unique per database.

The **value** field holds the function definition.

In the **mongo** shell, you can use

> db.loadServerScripts()

to load all the scripts saved in the `system.js` collection for the current database. Once loaded, you can invoke the functions directly in the shell, as in the following example:

```
db.loadServerScripts();

echoFunction(3);

myAddFunction(3, 5);
```

Source: [MONGODB MANUAL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/)

Answer (score 5):

You can call your function like this

```
db.loadServerScripts();
db.data.insert({
   _id: myFunction(5),
    name: "TestStudent"
});
```

if my function is stored in db using command:

```
db.system.js.save(
 {
  _id : "myFunction" ,
  value : function (x){ return x + 1; }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use $where for it to work!
something like this:

```
db.urls.find( { needParse: false, $where: function(item){
        if(item.date < cndTime)  // check
            db.urls.update({_id: item._id}, {$set: { needParse: true }});
```

for more information read this:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/