# in Robo3T, how to add a custom function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, robo3t

I just installed Robo3T( previously named robomongo), which has a GUI for mongo db.
I want to add a custom function to help me get the last N documents in normal order, the query statement is like this:

```
db.getCollection('i1801').find().skip(db.getCollection('i1801').count() - 1200)
```

And I found from stackoverflow([mongodb: how to get the last N records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421207/mongodb-how-to-get-the-last-n-records)), this can be written as a function like this:

```
function last(N) {
    return db.collection.find().skip(db.collection.count() - N);
}
```

And I go back to my Robo3T, trying to add a custom function `last()`, but didn't work, nothing showed up under function tab.

I have attached some screen captures illustrating this issue:

[image: Trying to add a custom function]

[image: Created a custom function and saved]

[image: After save, nothing happened]

After I clicked save button, nothing happened, still no functions under function tab. And the log shows function `last` created, and function tab being refreshed.
[image: Here is the logs]

So, how can I add a `last` function here?

Answer (score 4):

Tried the steps you listed, it worked for simple find statements. When I added the 'skip', the save failed. Even updating an existing function didn't work. Maybe an issue with Robo? I dont know.

Anyway, to add the function in Robo3t

1. Right click collection
2. Select Open Shell
3. On the shell type the following

```html
db.system.js.save(
   {
     _id: "last",
     value : function last(x) { return db.test.find().skip(db.test.count() - x); }
   }
)
```

Lastly, Run the script and refresh Function folder.

Comment: Thanks, now the function has been created, but I might have to ask some dumb questions since I don't know js or familiar with Robo3T. After created the function `last`, how can I use it. I've tryied to run `last(5)` , `db.getCollection('rb1801').last(5)`, or `db.last(5)` all don't work. Any advice?

Comment: For starters you can look into this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185192/call-stored-function-in-mongodb

Answer (score 2):

**For calling function:**

> db.loadServerScripts(); 
>  callyourfunction();

1. Right click on collection
2. Click on open shell
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTiGc.jpg
3. In shell run db.loadServerScripts();
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDTBT.jpg
4. call user function like:  addTwo(2,5);
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/EujGo.jpg

**NOTE :: For seen output, Make sure your function should be a return value**