# call a stored js file in mongoDB from python

Tags: python, mongodb

I stored a js function in my mongoDb and want to send data to it and receive answer from python.

which module can help ?

i have  many JavaScript function in Mongo and want call one of them from python and it call otherOnes,

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185192/call-stored-function-in-mongodb

Comment: i exactly save my function same way and call them from mongoshell . but now i need call them from python

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the string as python code using built-in function exec(string)

```
a = 'Your Python Code from mongo as string'
exec(a)
```

Example:

```
a = '''def ast():
       array =[1,2,3,4]
       return a
'''
exec(a)
ast()
```

output:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: i need a function from mongoDB becuse it call many other function in mongo i cant save my codes as string